# C# - Remove two types of string from a string

Tags: c#

My approach is not working because `description` doesn't remove the following:

I want to remove `->(no space and a number 0-9)` and `-> (space and a number 0-9)`

I've tried this:

```
description = description.Replace("->" + "[^-?0-9]+", "");
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: for regular expression I would use Regex

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i dont know what's that

Comment: you are using regular expression to define numbers pattern. How is it possible that you don't know what is that? :) Check `Regex.Replace`

Comment: google is my friend.

Comment: It kinda looks like you're trying to use regular expressions, but if description is a `string` then you are replacing the literal string and not the pattern.

Comment: description is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Regex.Replace` with regular expression (pattern) which you want to replace in the input:

```
description = Regex.Replace(description, @"-> ?\d", "")
```

Note that you are saying that you want to remove the single number. If you want to remove sequence of numbers, you should change `\d` to `\d+`

Explanation:

- `?` is a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) which makes preceding item optional (whitespace in your case)
- `\d` matches a single digit
- `+` (if you need it) is a quantifier which matches preceding item one or more times